# Why does my dynamically created array of custom types return with null value instances?

Tags: c#, arrays, createinstance

So I created this simple code to create an array dynamically- expecting two "empty/uninitialized" objects at index 0 and 1. However I get an array of objects in variable r that are both null?

I'm missing something so fundamental... I don't get it.
Thanks in advance.

```
public class myclass
{
    int a;
    string b;
    float c;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Type t = Type.GetType("ConsoleApplication1.myclass");
        var r = Array.CreateInstance(t.GetElementType(), 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just say `myclass[] r = new myclass[2]`?  It does the same thing but with less code and ensures the array is strongly typed.

Answer (score 2):

That's the way arrays work.  They are initially populated with `default(TheTypeOfTheArray)` which, for all reference types (this is a reference type) is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Creating an array doesn't mean initializing its objects. If `ConsoleApplication1.myclass` has no parameterless constructor, for example, how do you expect the CLR to create an instance of it implicitly?

Take this class, for instance.

```
class Foo
{
    public Foo(int value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

Using the following code:

```
var array = new Foo[10];
```

You will get a `Foo[]` which has ten `null` elements inside of it. The reason is explained above.

Comment: I expected the default constructor, generated by the compiler to produce an array of objects similar to those you'd find if you stated: var x = new myclass(); In this case, a=0, b=null and c=0.0

Comment: @Stratton That would happen if your `myclass` was declared as a `struct`.